# How do I make a voltage switcher using transistors?

Tags: voltage, transistors, controller

I have a 12V battery connected to an electromagnet. I need to be able to change the input voltage from 12V to 9V using a transistor. I was thinking of something that changes the voltage path to a more resistive one. I am just starting out with electrical engineering, so if someone could help clarify this problem it would be great.

Comment: Why a transistor? A simple resistor would do the job but if you want to to do it more efficiently read about buck converters.

Comment: `I need to be able to change this input voltage from 12V to 9V using a transistor` Do you mean switching the input to a separate 9V source or decreasing the input voltage to 9V?

Comment: *...using transistors.* As many beginners, you focus on **what components to use** but then forget to explain what you're actually trying to achieve. My advice: **forget about the transistors**, we can discuss circuits and transistors only **after** we know what you want. So make a schematic drawing (there's a tool for that when you edit your question) and show how you want to connect battery and electromagnet and use switches and voltage sources etc. But no transistors yet! Then when that's clear we can guide you to how a switch can be replaced by a transistor (or a relay).

Answer (score 0):

For 3V voltage droping the switched regulator does not have much advatage over classic resistive way because of switched regulator efficiency (about 80%). For higher drop they are good choice.

Here are the three examples, in first you must know the load resistance to calc the shunt. In second and third you dont need it. The second is based on a constant voltage drop of diode (0.7v) where four diodes in series creates about 2.8v drop. The third one uses a 10v zener diode to hold a 9.3v constant voltage over the load (the 0.7 is lost on BE junction).

[image]

Comment: Nonsense, you can easily make a buck converter to do this with efficiency in the mid 90s. That's a big improvement and a whole lot less heat than the 75% that these designs all provide.

Comment: @Finbarr is right, please adjust your opening statement. Buck converters are in one-IC-army nowadays, which means a very small footprint, and some of these can handle a few A easily.

Comment: even for a minimal drop a switched regulator can make sense. It is not the voltage drop that counts, but the resulting power loss. The 3 circuit diagrams are the same in this context. It doesn't matter whether a resistor, diode or transistor burns the power. Or?